# How to change buttons on a msgbox using a combo box in visual basic 2010 express?

Tags: vb.net

I want to display a **msgbox** that contains information provided by a **combo box**. Specifically, if the combo box contains "Warning" I want the msgbox to display the warning icon.

Basically I need to know how to put the input from the combo box into the msgbox without having to make it have `MsgBoxStyle.Critical` or something like that.

What I thought would work:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As system.object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Warning" Then
   ComboOutput = Msgboxstyle.critical
```

Hopefully my question is clear.

Comment: you should tag your question with vb not vbscript. And edit: mark your code and hit `{}`

Comment: Why didn't that work?  What's ComboOutput declared as?  Where's the MessageBox.Show code?

Comment: `Dim ComboOutput as MessageBoxIcon` then `ComboOutput = MessageBoxIcon.Warning` inside your if statement?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

We load all the enum values on form load. Then on click we parse the name and display the message box.

```
Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.DataSource = [Enum].GetNames(GetType(MessageBoxIcon))
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim value = [Enum].Parse(GetType(MessageBoxIcon), CStr(ComboBox1.SelectedItem))
    MessageBox.Show("Text", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OK, CType(value, MessageBoxIcon))
End Sub
```